# EXCEL Set sheet order when copying to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to control the order of worksheets when copying to another workbook? My code lists the order in which I'd like the sheets to appear in the new workbook, but the "Fail" sheet keeps ending up last in the tab order. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
wb.Save
wb.Sheets(Array("Fail", "Fail Screenshot", "Fail Screenshot2", "Fail Screenshot3", "Fail Screenshot4")).Copy
Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook
fileName = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\TEST\" & Sheets("Fail").Range("M7").Value & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
If Len(Dir(tempFile)) <> 0 Then
Kill tempFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list fails only to keep "Fail" worksheet as the first one then just move it:

```
wb.Sheets(Array("Fail", "Fail Screenshot", "Fail Screenshot2", "Fail Screenshot3", "Fail Screenshot4")).Copy
Sheets("Fail").Move Before:=Sheets(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to sort your sheets after copying to new workbook:

```
Sub sheetorders()
 Dim m, arr
 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 arr = Array("Fail", "Fail Screenshot", "Fail Screenshot2", "Fail Screenshot3", "Fail Screenshot4")
 wb.Save
 wb.Sheets(arr).Copy
 For Each m In arr
    Sheets(m).Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
 Next m
 Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook
 fileName = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\TEST\" & Sheets("Fail").Range("M7").Value & ".xlsx"
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
 If Len(Dir(tempFile)) <> 0 Then
 Kill tempFile
End Sub
```